# ViewState data not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

This is my Control that runs on my aspx page:

```
%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HostsControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="ClientFrontEnd.HostsControl" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/DataGridView.ascx" TagPrefix="dtbl" TagName="DataGridView" %>
<dtbl:DataGridView runat="server" id="tbl" />
```

It Uses another control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DataGridView.ascx.cs" Inherits="ClientFrontEnd.UserControls.DataGridView" %>
<asp:UpdatePanel UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server" ID="updatePanel">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgExportToExcel" EventName="Click" />
        <%--<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="imgExportToPDF" EventName="Click" />--%>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="upprogress" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatePanel" DisplayAfter="0">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="position: fixed; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%; top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.7;">
                    <asp:Image ID="imgUpdateProgress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/iguloader-yashar.gif" AlternateText="Loading ..." ToolTip="Loading ..." Style="padding: 10px; position: fixed; top: 45%; left: 50%;" />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="exportControls">
            <div id="div_export_images" style="text-align:right;">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExportToExcel" ImageUrl="~/images/files/excel.png" ToolTip="Export to excel" AlternateText="Excel" OnClick="ExportToExcel" runat="server" />
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgExportToPDF" ImageUrl="~/images/files/pdf.png" ToolTip="Export to pdf" AlternateText="PDF" OnClick="ExportToPDF" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </asp:PlaceHolder>
        <asp:Table runat="server" ID="table" CssClass="dataTable cell-border <%=CssClass%>" Width="100%" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

On the Page_Load of HostControl i set:

```
ViewState["searchParams"] = "test";
```

After the user clicks `ExportToExcel` it calls a method `GetDataToExport` from HostControl:

```
private DataTable GetDataToExport(out int[] columnsIndexes)
    {
        ViewState["searchParams"] -> null
    }
```

I dont understand why is it null and how can i do it otherwise/ When i put Session insted of ViewState it works, but it is not logicly correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ViewState["searchParams"] = dt;
DataTable dt2 = (DataTable)ViewState["searchParams"];
```

You can first store and after access like that. Also in your `IsPostBack`, you should call it.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {  
        if (!IsPostBack)  
        {  
            GetDataToExport(out int[] columnsIndexes); 
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's null because ViewState is unique to every control so once ViewState variable is initialized in one control it cannot be accessed in another one (even internally it has protected access modifier). To share data between the controls you can use, as you did, the session variable. But doing so you define it as a global variable and that's not very nice. So to do it nicely, the "object-oriented way", you can create public method in DataGridView control where you initialize `ViewState["searchParams"]` variable:

```
public void SetSearchParameters(string searchParams)
{
   ViewState["searchParams"] = searchParams;
}
```

Then in you host control in HostsControl (in Page_Load method) just call:

```
dtbl.SetSearchParameters(mySearchParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

After Inherits , Add `EnableViewState="true"` and Try.

for example

```
Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="...." EnableViewState="true"
```